# AWS connect from chromebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, chromebook

I have a network of Raspberry Pis that I access through a virtual private network on Amazon. The vpn is openvpn. To access the group from a Windows PC I issue the command

putty -i my_key.ppk ec2-user@(...ip address)

I guess my_key is a public key file. How do I do this with a Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

go into the EC2 page, check the box of the instance you want to connect to, then click connect at the top. you dont need putty, just open a terminal and use ssh. it gives you the whole command to paste and as long as you have your pem file you will be all set.

here is a chromebook app you can use for ssh

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-app/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo